# Limiting number of input values in an array/list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, input, split

I'm obtaining input values in a list using the following statement:

```
ar = map(int, raw_input().split())
```

However, I would want to limit the number of inputs a user can give at a time. For instance, if the limit is specified by a number n, the array should only capture the first n values entered during the program.

e.g: if n = 6,
Input:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

On performing 'print ar', it should display the following without any error messages:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: And it should ignore the rest of the input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to ignore the rest of the input, then you can use slicing to take only the first `n` input. Example -

```
n = 6
ar = map(int, raw_input().split(None, n)[:n])
```

We are also using the `maxsplit` option for `str.split` so that it only splits 6 times , and then takes the first 6 elements and converts them to int.

This is for a bit more performance. We can also do the simple - `ar = map(int, raw_input().split())[:n]` but it would be less performant than the above solution.

Demo -

```
>>> n = 6
>>> ar = map(int, raw_input().split(None, n)[:n])
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 6
>>> print ar
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Bravo! Thanks, that's a quite elegant solution, just what I wanted. I'm quite new to python, and slicing is quite a fresh concept for me.

Comment: Actually I found that using the statement: 'ar = map(int, raw_input().split())[:n] ' works as well. Arguments don't have to be provided for the split() function call.

Comment: Yes, I have explained that in my answer. My first solution was that. But then for a bit more performance I gave the current solution.

Comment: With simple slicing like that you would be taking all the numbers in the input , splitting them all, and then converting them all to int before slicing and getting the first `n` results.

Comment: Ah ok, can't see how I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

How about indexing `ar` to just the 6th element? Technically, it's to the 7th element, as `newarray` will slice up to, but not including nth element

```
ar = map(int, raw_input().split())
print ar
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

newarray=ar[0:6]
print newarray
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

This should allow for unlimited input

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution to the same question.

I figured out what I can do below is my solution.

```
bookid = []
M = int(input())
S = input().split()
for i in range(M):
    books.append(S[i])
print(booksid)
```

But I think it's definitely not the most effective way to do it but easy.